# How to get this command working on Alpine Linux?

Tags: linux, alpine-linux

On Ubuntu I can print a list of addresses in a specific range (given a base address) like the following:

```
seq -s " " -f "1.1.1.%g" 1 255
```

How can I achieve the same task on Alpine? `seq` provided by BusyBox is very limited in comparison and doesn't give me a format option.

Comment: anecdotally, do note that `1.1.1.1` is actually a valid public address as of 2018 and using it for an internal network may cause issues on some devices https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1.1.1.1

Comment: Yes, it was just an example address to explain the issue

Answer (score 1):

I've found a more straight forward solution using bash inside alpine:

```
apk add bash
echo 1.1.1.{1..255}
```

Comment: clear and obvious for the simple case!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python 3, you can generate the addresses in a network with the [`ipaddress` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) which may actually be better for your needs because it fully understands the masking (for example here it does not include `.255` because it's the broadcast address)

You can also change the separator from `" "` to `"\n"` if you want them on each line or something else

```py
% python3 -c 'import ipaddress;print(" ".join(str(x) for x in ipaddress.ip_network("1.1.1.0/24").hosts()))'
1.1.1.1 1.1.1.2 1.1.1.3 1.1.1.4 1.1.1.5 1.1.1.6 1.1.1.7 1.1.1.8 1.1.1.9 1.1.1.10 1.1.1.11 1.1.1.12 1.1.1.13 1.1.1.14 1.1.1.15 1.1.1.16 1.1.1.17 1.1.1.18 1.1.1.19 1.1.1.20 1.1.1.21 1.1.1.22 1.1.1.23 1.1.1.24 1.1.1.25 1.1.1.26 1.1.1.27 1.1.1.28 1.1.1.29 1.1.1.30 1.1.1.31 1.1.1.32 1.1.1.33 1.1.1.34 1.1.1.35 1.1.1.36 1.1.1.37 1.1.1.38 1.1.1.39 1.1.1.40 1.1.1.41 1.1.1.42 1.1.1.43 1.1.1.44 1.1.1.45 1.1.1.46 1.1.1.47 1.1.1.48 1.1.1.49 1.1.1.50 1.1.1.51 1.1.1.52 1.1.1.53 1.1.1.54 1.1.1.55 1.1.1.56 1.1.1.57 1.1.1.58 1.1.1.59 1.1.1.60 1.1.1.61 1.1.1.62 1.1.1.63 1.1.1.64 1.1.1.65 1.1.1.66 1.1.1.67 1.1.1.68 1.1.1.69 1.1.1.70 1.1.1.71 1.1.1.72 1.1.1.73 1.1.1.74 1.1.1.75 1.1.1.76 1.1.1.77 1.1.1.78 1.1.1.79 1.1.1.80 1.1.1.81 1.1.1.82 1.1.1.83 1.1.1.84 1.1.1.85 1.1.1.86 1.1.1.87 1.1.1.88 1.1.1.89 1.1.1.90 1.1.1.91 1.1.1.92 1.1.1.93 1.1.1.94 1.1.1.95 1.1.1.96 1.1.1.97 1.1.1.98 1.1.1.99 1.1.1.100 1.1.1.101 1.1.1.102 1.1.1.103 1.1.1.104 1.1.1.105 1.1.1.106 1.1.1.107 1.1.1.108 1.1.1.109 1.1.1.110 1.1.1.111 1.1.1.112 1.1.1.113 1.1.1.114 1.1.1.115 1.1.1.116 1.1.1.117 1.1.1.118 1.1.1.119 1.1.1.120 1.1.1.121 1.1.1.122 1.1.1.123 1.1.1.124 1.1.1.125 1.1.1.126 1.1.1.127 1.1.1.128 1.1.1.129 1.1.1.130 1.1.1.131 1.1.1.132 1.1.1.133 1.1.1.134 1.1.1.135 1.1.1.136 1.1.1.137 1.1.1.138 1.1.1.139 1.1.1.140 1.1.1.141 1.1.1.142 1.1.1.143 1.1.1.144 1.1.1.145 1.1.1.146 1.1.1.147 1.1.1.148 1.1.1.149 1.1.1.150 1.1.1.151 1.1.1.152 1.1.1.153 1.1.1.154 1.1.1.155 1.1.1.156 1.1.1.157 1.1.1.158 1.1.1.159 1.1.1.160 1.1.1.161 1.1.1.162 1.1.1.163 1.1.1.164 1.1.1.165 1.1.1.166 1.1.1.167 1.1.1.168 1.1.1.169 1.1.1.170 1.1.1.171 1.1.1.172 1.1.1.173 1.1.1.174 1.1.1.175 1.1.1.176 1.1.1.177 1.1.1.178 1.1.1.179 1.1.1.180 1.1.1.181 1.1.1.182 1.1.1.183 1.1.1.184 1.1.1.185 1.1.1.186 1.1.1.187 1.1.1.188 1.1.1.189 1.1.1.190 1.1.1.191 1.1.1.192 1.1.1.193 1.1.1.194 1.1.1.195 1.1.1.196 1.1.1.197 1.1.1.198 1.1.1.199 1.1.1.200 1.1.1.201 1.1.1.202 1.1.1.203 1.1.1.204 1.1.1.205 1.1.1.206 1.1.1.207 1.1.1.208 1.1.1.209 1.1.1.210 1.1.1.211 1.1.1.212 1.1.1.213 1.1.1.214 1.1.1.215 1.1.1.216 1.1.1.217 1.1.1.218 1.1.1.219 1.1.1.220 1.1.1.221 1.1.1.222 1.1.1.223 1.1.1.224 1.1.1.225 1.1.1.226 1.1.1.227 1.1.1.228 1.1.1.229 1.1.1.230 1.1.1.231 1.1.1.232 1.1.1.233 1.1.1.234 1.1.1.235 1.1.1.236 1.1.1.237 1.1.1.238 1.1.1.239 1.1.1.240 1.1.1.241 1.1.1.242 1.1.1.243 1.1.1.244 1.1.1.245 1.1.1.246 1.1.1.247 1.1.1.248 1.1.1.249 1.1.1.250 1.1.1.251 1.1.1.252 1.1.1.253 1.1.1.254
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think that using just echo is much simpler and doesn't require python installed.

Comment: anytime and certainly so! however, this is quite practical for more nuanced examples and can calculate directly from an existing interface, such as `ipaddress.ip_interface("172.16.100.18/28").network.hosts()` (`.17-.30`)